# com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission not granted

Tags: java, android, android-permissions

I've added com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND in the manifest as shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.lewwe.broadcastsender">
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

However, when I use the following code to check if the permission is granted, it returns a result that is not granted

```
    int res = getApplicationContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission("com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND");
    if (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        System.out.println("GRANTED");
    else
        System.out.println("NOT GRANTED");
```

I got the following error log when I try to interact with another broadcast receiver from another app that requires the com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission:

```
03-31 07:44:21.648 675-691/? W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { flg=0x10 cmp=cn.wps.moffice_eng/cn.wps.moffice.main.gcm.GcmReceiver (has extras) } from com.example.lewwe.broadcastsender (pid=2680, uid=10077) requires com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND due to receiver cn.wps.moffice_eng/cn.wps.moffice.main.gcm.GcmReceiver
```

I am thinking that I have to request for this permission during runtime. If that is true, how do I do that?

Comment: can you update your question with error log?

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

> The com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND permission is held by Google Play services. This prevents other apps from invoking the broadcast receiver.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking that I have to request for this permission during runtime.

You don't need to **request** this permission,  in fact you can't, because it would allow you to send push notification messages to other apps on the device. Instead, you need to specify your receiver's [`android:permission` property](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#prmsn) so that only applications with this permission will send this intent to your broadcast receiver. Otherwise, any application can send this intent and launch your application.

For example, in Firebase Messaging, they do:

```xml
    <receiver
      android:name=".FlutterFirebaseMessagingReceiver"
      android:exported="true"
      android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

> `android:permission`: The name of a permission that broadcasters must
> have to send a message to the broadcast receiver. If this attribute is
> not set, the permission set by the  element's permission
> attribute applies to the broadcast receiver. If neither attribute is
> set, the receiver is not protected by a permission. - [documentation on `receiver`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element#prmsn)